# How can I replace different format strings using a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to turn the string `"date: %H:%M:%S:%MS"` into `"date: 01:02:03:04"`. That is, replace each format specifier with the right number.

```js
const date = {
    H: '01',
    M: '02',
    S: '03',
    MS: '04',
}
const format = 'date: %H:%M:%S:%MS';
format.replace(/%[H,M,S,MS]/g, (f) => date[f]); // like this but it's not working
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Loop over the keys of the `date` and perform a replacement on the format, replacing the `%${key}` with the value of that key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. What you want is:

```
format.replace(/%(H|M|S|MS)\b/g, (_, f) => date[f]);
// date: 1:2:3:4
```

Matching different groups of characters is done with a capture group `()` using pipes `|`, and you also want only what is matched inside the capture group (second argument passed to the function). Finally, the `\b` matches a word boundary: you don't want `%MS` to be matched by the first `M` in the capture group, you only want to do that in the case `%M:` where after the `M` there is a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

If you want to also have padding zeroes:

```
format.replace(/%(H|M|S|MS)\b/g, (_, f) => date[f].toString().padStart(2, '0'));
// date: 01:02:03:04
```

Or, much simpler, if you are willing to modify `date` a little bit:

```
const date = {
    '%H': '01',
    '%M': '02',
    '%S': '03',
    '%MS': '04',
};

const format = 'date: %H:%M:%S:%MS';
format.replace(/%(H|M|S|MS)\b/g, f => date[f]);
// date: 01:02:03:04
```

Comment: Instead of `f => date[f.substr(1)]` you could also use `(_, p1) =>date[p1]`. Where `p1` holds the matched characters in capture group 1.

Comment: This behaviour is described in the `replace()` [Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I may see at least 3 issues with your code:

- square brackets do not work the way you expect them in your RegExp
- matching substring (inside the capturing group) is the second argument of `.replace()` callback
- values of your `date` object are of type `Number`, so you're going to loose `0` (e.g. `01` turns into `1`)

If get fixed all of the above, you may end up with something, like that:

```js
const date = {
          H: 01,
          M: 02,
          S: 03,
          MS: 04,
      },
      format = 'date: %H:%M:%S:%MS',

      result = format.replace(
        /%(MS|H|M|S)/g, 
        (_,m) => 
          `${date[m]}`.padStart(2, '0')
      )
    
console.log(result)
```